# Change title color of UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new on iOS development.

I'm trying to change the title and message color of a UIAlertController but is not working, the color is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("notifications_popup2_title", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("notifications_popup2_message", comment: ""), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        // Change font of the title and message
        let titleFont:[NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [ NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue) : UIFont(name: "Flama-Basic", size: 22)!, NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor(hexString: "#2e2e2e")! ]
        let messageFont:[NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [ NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue) : UIFont(name: "Flama-light", size: 18)!, NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor(hexString: "#2e2e2e")! ]
        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("notifications_popup2_title", comment: ""), attributes: titleFont)
        let attributedMessage = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("notifications_popup2_message", comment: ""), attributes: messageFont)
        alert.setValue(attributedTitle, forKey: "attributedTitle")
        alert.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

If i change alert style to `.alert` it is working...

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain what you mean by "but is not working". Also, read [ask].

Comment: I upload a screenshot. I think is not detecting the color

Comment: UIAlertController's title/message take a string property, not an attributed string, so I;d expect them not to work.  I'm guessing that it works for an alert for legacy compatibility reasons.

Comment: Don't. That's using private properties/libs, it could change as it did (between iOS 12 & iOS13 for instance) and so not work anymore, and someday could be a reason from Apple to reject the app. Instead create your own customized one.

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224830/ios-13-uialertcontroller-color-change-in-attributedmessage-and-attributedtitle?noredirect=1#comment102826246_58224830

Answer (score 1):

Some of the code you used are deprecated like:

```
NSAttributedStringKey
```

is now:

```
NSAttributedString.Key
```

also you don't need to specify the `rawValue`. you just need something like:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "title", attributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "message", attributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue]), forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Result:
[image: Alert]

**Note that** it only works for `.alert`. `.actionSheet` title and message is not colorable unlike the `.alert`

Also **be aware** that Using private API can cause rejection. But experience shows that only private methods that their name starts with "_" cause rejection from *AppStore private method usage detection* system.

**Also** can stop working anytime if apple decides to change it.

The best option you have is to implement a custom alert yourself.

Comment: You are absolutely right @Sulthan. but experience shows that only private methods that their name starts with "_" cause rejection from *AppStore private method usage detection* system. I mentioned that in the answer. Thanks

Comment: I am not talking about rejections, I am talking about the fact the this needs a warning. Using a custom alert controller is usually safer.

Comment: Sorry I missed understand that. You are right as always. I have updated the answer and mentioned both issues. Thanks again @Sulthan

Comment: It just changed, FYI in IOS13: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224830/ios-13-uialertcontroller-color-change-in-attributedmessage-and-attributedtitle?noredirect=1#comment102826246_58224830